# How to install Django based Project?

Tags: python, django

i have Django based Blog Application.

File structure image :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vnqwheucjeyy43/Selection_012.png

Here no manage.py file.

How can i run it locally ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first create a django project: `django-admin.py startproject <projectname>`

then the directory with `<projectname>` will be created with these files:

```
--projectname
  --settings.py
  --urls.py
  --wsgi.py

--manage.py
```

now copy the folder `blog` to `<projectname>` directory.

### edit settings.py:

#### add database details.

```
import os
path=os.path.dirname(__file__)
............... other settings.py variables

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': path+'/tt.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

#### add `blog` to settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....other apps
    'blog',
)
```

#### edit `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(path, '..','blog','static') 
)
```

### edit urls.py

add required blog urls to `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...other urlpatterns
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

### run the site

```
python manage.py collectstatic
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py runserver
```

you can now visit : 127.0.0.1:8000